# VPN Server + Anonymity + Adblock for mobile Devices

Tags: vpn, android, proxy

In order to improve private security and anonymity while browsing the web on my mobile devices I wanted to tunnel all traffic to my own server via VPN and use a proxy software to filter unwanted (Tracking, Advertisement) requests out.

Currently I'm using a OpenVPN server and a separate [privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) instance.

VPN works fine but unfortunately there is no option for system-wide proxy in Android (without rooting the phone). Therefore I would like to know if there exists a plugin for OpenVPN or any other method to combine those two?

Idea:
Tunnel Traffic via OpenVPN to the server. On the server-side a proxy filters in and outgoing HTTP requests (optional: minify).

Links to tutorials appreciated.

Comment: Use that machine's firewall to redirect HTTP traffic (on port 80) to a transparent proxy (Squid can do it, I assume Privoxy can be configured to do it).

Comment: @AndréDaniel can you point me to a tutorial where I can find additional information on how to do this?

Comment: Search for "squid transparent proxy". As a sidenote, a transparent proxy isn't that great of an idea as it won't be able to filter HTTPS content, you better use a "normal" proxy (by specifying it in the phone's settings) so you can also filter HTTPS connections based on the destination hostname.

Comment: @user42178 The destination hostname will be visible in the SNI extension. He could also install a local CA and break the TLS at his server.